# Dynamo DB query using index which is not primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, documentclient

I have a Dynamo DB table which has a primary key as well as a secondary index (routeId).
I need to retrieve records containing the secondary index. However, I need to get results for multiple routeId values in a single run. Any way to do it?

Comment: No you cannot read multiple items in a single query from secondary index. You can however do it from the base table in signle query using `batchGet`.

Comment: @PrakashSharma Can batchGet used for the secondary index? It can only be used with the primary key, right?

Comment: Yeah thats what i said. You cannot use `batchGet` on secondary indexes. You can only use it on base table.